# Why is my string variable in Audiobooks(secondaryform) not considered a member of ShoppingCart(mainform)

Tags: vb.net

I instantiated a place in memory with the `Dim MyCollection As New AudioBooks` statement in the `Public Class ShoppingCart` Shopping cart form.  Here is where I declared my variable in audiobooks `Dim StrLearnCalclusInOneDayAB As String` in the `Public Class AudioBooks` form.

```
If ListBox1.Items.Contains(Me.MyCollection.StrLearnCalclusInOneDayAB)
```

Here is my main syntax error, I need to look through listbox1 to see if the variable from audiobooks is there.  I qualifying this wrong, and i know its so frustratingly simple.
Here is the full code.  I need a VB tutor and will pay $5 per question below is the code in full.

```
Public Class ShoppingCart
Dim Tax As Decimal
Dim PB1 As Decimal
Dim AB1 As Decimal
Dim MyCollection As New AudioBooks

'My overall objective is to move the strings from audiobooks and printbooks to shopping cart and calculate the total
'I was instructed to use a module



Private Sub Label3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label3.Click
    Tax = 0.06
End Sub

Private Sub PrintBooksToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PrintBooksToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Create an instance of the printbook
    Dim frmPrintBook As New PrintBook

    'Display the form in modal styple
    frmPrintBook.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub AudioBooksToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AudioBooksToolStripMenuItem.Click
    'Create an instance of the audiobook
    Dim frmAudioBook As New AudioBooks

    'Display the form in modal style
    frmAudioBook.ShowDialog()
End Sub


Public Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    'Dim MyCollection As New AudioBooks
    'I want to run an if else statement which checks Listbox1 to see what books are in the cart and calculates the total
    'I'm having trouble finding these variables(from audiobooks) with intelligsense, 'StrLearnCalclusInOneDayAB' etc.
    'I'm pretty sure I need a new instance of memory from the audio bookcooks class to use the object variables
    'declared in that class.  I'm having trouble getting the syntax right.  Intelligsense only will find the lstboxaudio

    'The book says, form's class-level variables are accessible to statements in the form file,
    'they are not accessible by default to statements outside the form file



    'I want the code to look like this,  only lstboxAudio comes up in Intelligsense, why is this, I want StrLearnCalclusInOneDayAB to
    'Also I'm not sure I'm using contains correctly, hope I was clear

    'I will eventually need to total the books in the cart, why Can't intellisense find the variable?
    'This is my primary question



    If ListBox1.Items.Contains(MyCollection.StrLearnCalclusInOneDayAB) Then

    End If


    Cart.IDidItYourWay = 11.95
    Cart.TheHistoryofScotland = 14.5
    Cart.LearnCalculusInOneDay = 29.95
    Cart.FeelTheStress = 18.5

    Cart.LearnCalculusInOneDayAB = 29.95
    Cart.RelaxationTechniques = 11.5
    Cart.TheScienceOfBodyLanguage = 12.95
    Cart.TheHistoryOfScotlandAB = 14.5
    'I feel I shouldn't have to reference an object to change properties in a class, why must I do that?  
    'This question might not make sense.  
End Sub


Private Sub lblSubtotal_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblSubtotal.Click

End Sub
```

End Class

```
Public Class AudioBooks

Public Sub lstboxAudio_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstboxAudio.SelectedIndexChanged


End Sub

Public Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Dim AudioBooks1 As String
    'AudioBooks1 = lstboxAudio.SelectedItem.ToString
    'Save the selected item to a string
    'ShoppingCart.ListBox1.Items.Add(AudioBooks1)
    'shopping cart form, listbox1, items, add, that string of audiobooks

    Dim StrLearnCalclusInOneDayAB As String
    StrLearnCalclusInOneDayAB = lstboxAudio.Items(0).ToString
    'If strLearnCalculusInOneDayAB is selected then add to the shopping cart listbox

    If lstboxAudio.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        ShoppingCart.ListBox1.Items.Add(StrLearnCalclusInOneDayAB)
    End If
    ' if the selectedindex of lslboxaudio is 0, the string is selected
    'then move it to the shoppingcart

    Dim StrTheHistoryOfScotlandAB As String
    StrTheHistoryOfScotlandAB = lstboxAudio.Items(1).ToString

    If lstboxAudio.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        ShoppingCart.ListBox1.Items.Add(StrTheHistoryOfScotlandAB)
    End If


    Dim StrTheScienceOfBodyLangAB As String
    StrTheScienceOfBodyLangAB = lstboxAudio.Items(2).ToString

    If lstboxAudio.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        ShoppingCart.ListBox1.Items.Add(StrTheScienceOfBodyLangAB)
    End If


    Dim StrRelaxationTechniquesAB As String
    StrRelaxationTechniquesAB = lstboxAudio.Items(3).ToString

    If lstboxAudio.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        ShoppingCart.ListBox1.Items.Add(StrRelaxationTechniquesAB)
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 0):

It relates to the Dim statement being classified private by default in the Audiobooks form.  The must explicitly be declared public.  Not knowing access levels and static shared variable dynamics creates this Question.